# Magento get id value which is given cms block

Tags: magento-1.9, banner-slider

I have created one custom banner, I have added banner block in cms home page in that place I have provided banner id.

How to get that banner id in phtml file?

```
{{block type="simplebanner/simplebanner" name="simplebannercmsblock" template="simplebanner/simplebanner.phtml" banner_id = "1"}}
```

I need to get banner id in simplebanner.phtml file

my block file having below code

```
public function _prepareLayout() {
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

public function getSimplebanner() {
    if (!$this->hasData('simplebanner')) {
        $this->setData('simplebanner', Mage::registry('simplebanner'));
    }
    return $this->getData('simplebanner');
}

public function getCollection() {

    $_collection = Mage::getModel('simplebanner/simplebanner')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);
    return $_collection;
}
```

Comment: @Piyush all answers correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get data by using this

```
echo $this->banner_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->getData('banner_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->getBannerId(); // in Block

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('simplebanner')->getBannerId(); // in Controller
```